# How do I create another window on top of a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm alittle confused about how to create a page on top of a page. Basically I want to have the page open with: Hi ________.

Then, when the user types the name in and presses enter, the name is then saved so that the page now writes "Hi [insert name here]!.

I'm not sure what is the best course of action. Should I should use a prompt, or an input text box? How would I be able to save the name provided? I'm not even sure if there is such an effect?

I know how to create a text input box, and how to make the form press enter with just the keyboard, but I don't know how to put the effect on top. How I can make a window on top of a window?

So the website prompts the user to

```
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


    <p id="demo"></p>
```

After, the page fills in the name, the name will be inserted into the script. So the page will display the name entered. For example, "Hi Sam." in the regular 
page. Would I use a version of this?

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
```

Let me know if this sounds too confusing. I can try to elaborate further. I've tried looking for a similar question on stackoverflow before, and I don't see one just like this yet.

Comment: Do you mean like a popup / modal? I would recommend using angular / bootstrap's modal: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal

Comment: @RadicalFanatic Sort of? Are there anything else that would make it possible? Sorry I'm new to javascript so I'm not sure aout angular or the bootstrap modal.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're looking for. People have shown so far how to make a new window or some very basic popups, but it sounds like you are looking to create some kind of popup that stays in the current browser window and is fully customizable. Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not mentioned any framework like angular or jquery in your post I guess you are fairly new to creating "dynamic" web pages with JavaScript. You *can* do these things with "pure JavaScript" but in general you will need to write more code. Your actual example, however, can be made to work with relatively little changes and not too much effort, like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Please enter your name">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

In this example no extra window was applied. If you *want* a *modal dialog* you could use the JavaScript window-method `prompt()`

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name here", "suggested name");
```

instead of the above `input` field:

```js
function myFunction() {
        var x = prompt("Please enter your name here", "suggested name");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a new window? Try this:

```
var theName = prompt("What is your name?");
var w = window.open("", "", "width=500, height=300");
w.document.body.innerHTML = "Hello "+theName+"!";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then, when the user types the name in and presses enter, the name is
>   then saved so that the page now writes "Hi [insert name here]!.

If you just want to save the data for the current session then you can save the data into a Javascript variable.

> I'm not sure what is the best course of action. Should I should use a
>   prompt, or an input text box? How would I be able to save the name
>   provided? I'm not even sure if there is such an effect?

Any of them would work, any field that can take a value.

> I know how to create a text input box, and how to make the form press
>   enter with just the keyboard, but I don't know how to put the effect
>   on top. How I can make a window on top of a window?

The term a window on top of a window isn't really accurate terminology. But I think I see what you mean. You can just use hide and show to hide the text field and then insert the name into a span.

I've made a fiddle so you can see what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/xo5vt07s/6/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#name").keypress(
        function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                    var usersName = document.getElementById("name");
                    var displayBox = document.getElementById("displayName");
                    usersName.style.display = "none";
                    displayBox.innerHTML = usersName.value + "!";
                    displayBox.style.display = "inline";
                alert("Test")
            }
        }
    );

});
```